# How to handle dynamic data in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my app I have items which are dynamically created based on an UI editor. The item details is a JSON.

The domain does not interact with the JSON details. The UI is responsable to create and render the details.

```
public class ItemDto {
     public JObject Details{ get; set; } // JObject is Newtonsonft.JObject 
}
```

```
public class ItemService {
   public void SaveItem(ItemDto itemDto) { 
        // Validate itemDto.Data

        var item = new Item();

        // Call repository to save the item
   }
}
```

In the domain, how do I represent it as entity, specifically the 'Details' property?

```
public class Item { 
     public int Id  { get; }

     // What data type should details have?   
     public ? Details { get; }
}
```

Should I encapsulate the item data into some ItemDetails class which I put in the domain?

```
public class Item { 
     public int Id  { get; }
     public ItemDetails Details { get; }
}
```

How do I protect the ItemDetails class so that I'm sure it's only created based on valid details data?

Maybe use a factory method?

```
public class ItemDetails {
     // Make ItemDetails c-tor private
     ItemDetails() {  }
  
     public static ItemDetails Create(JObject details, IServiceNeededForValidation service) {   // Since ItemData is in the domain, should the ItemDetails class use an JObject ?
          // parse data and make sure it's valid
     }
}
```

Since ItemDetails is in the domain, should the ItemDetials class use an JObject ?

Comment: Are the terms used in the question (Item, ItemData) terms you actually use in your domain? This question is unclear and needs more focus imo.

Comment: If it's unclear you can ask and I can try clarify. Down-voting is not necessary as it reduces the chance to be seen by others and for me to get help. Yes, Item and ItemData are part of the domain, I think I already mentioned that

Comment: Some people downvote without commenting, I didn't downvote, but I do think the question needs more focus. There are 4 questions in your post, perhaps you can rewrite your question to focus on the single most important issue?

Comment: It would also be useful if you could explain what DDD has to do with this, if anything.  Normally, DDD identifies objects that belong to your business domain; that's why it's called *Domain*-Driven Design.  Your example has none of that; all of your objects are of the most generic nature (an "item" doesn't describe a business domain; *anything* can be an "item.")

Comment: What is the issue you have with using `JObject`?   would you have the same issue for data in other non-primitive types such as a `Dictionary`?

Comment: I assume that ItemDetails is something business people also refer to so I assume it's part of the domain model. The question is, do the item details really contain some arbitrary data? E.g. can I as a user of the application enter some text and that's it? Or is it more like a complex entity or value object which differ in structure or business logic depending on different types of clients? I'd to understand your problem better. Does it relate to this question somehow or is it a different one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67361588/7730554

Comment: @afh To answer your questions: Yes, ItemDetails is something business people can refer to. ItemDetails contains dynamic properties of an Item which the UI editor allows to add and edit. Some properties are default and mandatory, cannot be removed (i.e. Name). Item is specific to the business, it exists in the app, only its properties can be dynamic. Clients can add and edit their own properties.

Answer (score 1):

> The domain does not interact with the JSON data. The UI is responsable to create and render the data.

Given the backend doesn't actually need to understand the JSON, why bother deserializing it to begin with? Just store the JSON as a string, which means you have *no* constraints on which fields it contains, and return the JSON string to the UI when requested.

```
public class Item 
{ 
    public int Id  { get; } 
    public string Data { get; }
}
```

> Should I encapsulate the item data into some ItemData class which I put in the domain?

If you're against primitive obsession, instead of using a raw string to store the JSON in, you might wrap that string in a class (such as `ItemData`).

IF your `Data` class contains nothing more than an ID and the JSON string, it's unnecessary to add another type on top of it. IF your `Data` class contains lots of things, it may be more relevant to abstract the JSON string to avoid primitive obsession. I wouldn't call it *necessary*, but there is justification to avoid primitives.

> How do I protect the ItemData class so that I'm sure it's only created based on valid data?

By your own statement, the backend doesn't interact with the JSON data. So why would it care that it is "valid"?

Furthermore, you haven't defined what validity entails.

- If it's about valid JSON syntax, look for a JSON validator
- If it's about the JSON containing specific fields, you'll have to deserialize and check if those fields (and their values) match the expectations

  - However, that doesn't mean you can't still store it as a JSON string after you're done validating.

> // Make ItemData c-tor private

Why? Why do this:

```
 public class ItemData 
 {
      // Make ItemData c-tor private
      ItemData() {  }

      public static ItemData Create(JObject data) 
      {
           // parse data and make sure it's valid
      }
 }
```

instead of this:

```
 public class ItemData 
 {
      public ItemData(JObject data) 
      {  
          // parse data and make sure it's valid
      }
 }
```

What's the difference? Why the static?

Note that I'm not saying that you should be using `JObject` here, I'm only discussing the way in which you intend to initialize your object.

This also starts getting into the much broader question of whether validation of a type should be contained in the type itself, or in a separate validator. There is no one-size-fits-all answer here. Depending on the complexity of your class and the validation, you might decide that they represent a single responsibility or not (because responsibilities are a matter of subjective granularity).

Comment: First, thank you very much for your input. I made few changes to my question. "Details" better describe it than "Data". Those are actually different dynamic item details. The reason I thought it's a good idea to encapsulate it is to protect it from being created or modified other than by the single way (which is what comes from the UI). The UI calls a web API to create a new item with with the given item details.

Comment: 2nd: The reason I wanted to use a factory method instead of a c-tor is to have a way to pass a service which can validate the details. The service needs repository to check different item details (some are id's of other entities).

Comment: My question is about where it's best to put validation and whether it makes sense to encapsulate the details. Having a 'string' for the details JSON doesn't sound good to me. If the code and logic evolves, how do I make sure the Item entity does not get created with invalid Details? How do I architect the classes and layers in a way it prevents accidental creation of an Item with the invalid details.

Comment: please let me know if it still not clear, I can provide more details, I just don't know upfront which are needed, Thank you

Comment: @Daniel (Comment 1) This is covered by the "deserialize and check if those fields (and their values) match the expectations" part of the answer. (Comment 2) Statics are not the way to go here, as they are not object-oriented and therefore can't partake in proper depencendy injection (Comment 3) Same answer as in (Comment 1).

Comment: @Daniel: You've also got a conceptual conflict here. **(A)** You talk about _dynamic_ data, which implies that the data you're handling might change structure during application lifetime, and you don't want to have to change your code or redeploy because of it. **(B)** But then you expect there to be validation that works based on specific fields. How are you going to write that validation logic, if not by knowing precisely which fields exist? Which argues against the idea that this data is dynamic, since you clearly know what fields to expect. A and B are in conflict with one another.

Comment: The client uses an UI editor to define the JSON (a schema) with custom properties stored in the ItemDetails. The validation I am referring to is validating the incoming ItemDetails to see if it matches the schema.